# convert R code to BNF form ( Backus–Naur form )

Tags: r, bnf

I am a complete newbie at this and may be my question is stupid, I apologize in advance.
I want to convert any piece of code to BNF form.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form

For example, here is some code (code can be completely different)

```
m = NULL
for(i in 1:10){
  m[i] = i 
}
```

I want to get something like this

```
<expr> ::=  <var><equ><null> ;
            for(<iter> in <vec>) { 
               <var><br><equ><iter>}
                               
<var>  ::= m
<equ>  ::= =
<br>   ::= [i]
<vec>  ::= 1:10
<iter> ::= i
<null> ::= NULL
```

There may be errors in my BNF form, take this as an illustration of what I would like to receive, and not as an exact example

I would like to get an example of how this is generally done

**===== upd =====**

I'm using grammatical evolution [gramEvol package](https://www.google.com/search?q=gramevol%20r&oq=grame&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i59j35i39i650j46i10i199i465i512l2j46i199i465i512j0i10i512j46i512j0i10i512l2.5651j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to find useful
expressions (R code)

[vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gramEvol/vignettes/ge-intro.pdf)

features of this package

1. takes the BNF form as input
2. generates different expressions
3. checks expressions against the fitness function

I would like to be able to generate the BNF for this package from my relatively small chunks of real R code.

Comment: You might want to read https://adv-r.hadley.nz/expressions.html and look at `lobstr::ast` (it's a _start_).

Comment: The grammar for R is defined in [gram.y](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/66811fc4e34424c504fe41285662e7089e71927f/src/main/gram.y). Usually you need the grammar first to parse an expression, I'm not familiar with any methods to infer the grammar from a chunk of code. As already pointed out you can get the abstract syntax tree from the R parser, but the three doesn't really tell you what the grammar is.

Comment: I need the bnf form. I'll be glad to see an example of how to get this from the finished grammar

Comment: I think you should be explaing why this is needed. For instance you apparently expect `m[i] = i ` to be decomposed into a sequence of `<var>  ::= m; 
<equ>  ::= =; 
<br>   ::= [i]`. To my eyes that means you done understand how the R parser will be handling that assignment. There is a specific R function whose "real" name is `[<-` and its 3 arguments are `m`, `i` and `i`. So are you in some sort of compiler/interpreter class and this is part of an assignment?

Comment: please see my update. If you have any more questions please ask